# C# (AOP) Method Interceptor

Tags: c#, function, methods, aop, interceptor

I have lots of web service methods and I want to validate all of them in one function.
For example;

```
[Intercept]
public string Method1(POS pos, int param1, string param2)
{
    return String.Format("{0}: {1}", param1,param2);
}

[Intercept]
public int Method2(POS pos, int param3)
{
    return param3 * 2;
}

public void OnPreProcessing(...)
{
     // Before Mothod1 and Method2 called, It should enter here
     // I want to be able to cancel method execution and return another value.
     // I want to get the method name, parameter names and values         
}
```

Now i'am using ContextBoundObject and IMessageSink to do this. I can get method name, parameters and values, but i can't cancel the method execution and return another value. I am using something like below.

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
{
    var mcm = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
    OnPreProcessing(ref mcm);
    var retMsg = _NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg) as IMethodReturnMessage;
    OnPostProcessing(mcm, ref retMsg);
    return retMsg;
}
```

How can I cancel the method execution and return another values?

Thanks.

Comment: please give more info about your "service". WCF ? Rest service ? Web Services ? Also Retag you question.

Comment: it is web services. However I have to do the operation for any methods not only WebMethods.

Answer (score 0):

Just place a cancelation detection to ignore call.

```
[Intercept]
public string Method1(POS pos, int param1, string param2)
{
    return String.Format("{0}: {1}", param1,param2);
}

[Intercept]
public int Method2(POS pos, int param3)
{
    return param3 * 2;
}

public bool OnPreProcessing(...)
{
     // Before Mothod1 and Method2 called, It should enter here
     // I want to be able to cancel method execution and return another value.
     // I want to get the method name, parameter names and values         
}
```

fore example, OnPreProcessing return a boolean that is true if you need to cancel the call...

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
{
    var mcm = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
    var cancel = OnPreProcessing(ref mcm);
    var retMsg = cancel ? /*IMethodReturnMessage for cancelation*/ : _NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg) as IMethodReturnMessage;
    OnPostProcessing(mcm, ref retMsg);
    return retMsg;
}
```